# Google app engine - rabbit mq alternative

Tags: google-app-engine, rabbitmq

I'm looking to move over a messaging system that we have over to the google app engine environment but I have a few questions that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

Our current message environment uses rabbit mq to process messages and then uses about 10 consumers that connect to the que to send the messages. This works well for us as having 10 consumer instances to process the messages dramatically increases delivery rates.

I understand that the app engine doesn't support rabbit mq so I was wondering what would be the best alternative to achieve the same result. I see that you can run tasks in the background which is great but this would only act as one instance, which will slow down the delivery rates.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use rabbitmq before, but your requirement looks like quite fit the usage of taskqueue and pipeline on app engine.

TaskQueue provide the ability to setup consumers and setup their process rate.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

> With the Task Queue API, applications can perform work outside of a user request, initiated by a user request. If an app needs to execute some background work, it can use the Task Queue API to organize that work into small, discrete units, called tasks. The app adds tasks to task queues to be executed later.

The piepline is based on taskqueue and provide more feature on control the flow.
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/

> The Google App Engine Pipeline API connects together complex, time-consuming workflows (including human tasks). The goals are flexibility, workflow reuse, and testability. A primary use-case of the API is connecting together various App Engine MapReduces into a computational pipeline.